# PSI: How to find declarations of a class

Tags: intellij-plugin

I have the `PsiClass` for my class. How do I find all declarations.

eg.

```
class Inner {
  MyBean myClass = new MyBean();
}

class Outer {
  void findDeclarations(Project project) {
    final var beanPsiClass = JavaPsiFacade.getInstance(project).findClass("MyBean", GlobalSearchScope.allScope(project));
    final var allBeans = ??? // Should find the declaration in Inner class
  }
}
```